# Swapping first and last names removing commas

Tags: python, swap

Using python 3.3:

I need some help in writing the body for this function that swaps the positions of the last name and first name.

Essentially, I have to write a body to swap the first name from a string to the last name's positions.

The initial order is first name followed by last name (separated by a comma). Example: 'Albus Percival Wulfric Brian, Dumbledore'

The result I want is: 'Dumbledore Albus Percival Wulfric Brian'

My approach was:
name = 'Albus Percival Wulfric Brian, Dumbledore
name = name[name.find(',')+2:]+", "+name[:name.find(',')]

the answer I get is: 'Dumbledore, Albus Percival Wulfric Brian' (This isn't what I want)
There should be no commas in between.

I'm a new user to Python, so please don't go into too complex ways of solving this.
Thanks kindly for any help!

Comment: Can you show us what you have so far?

Comment: name = 'Albus Percival Wulfric Brian, Dumbledore'
name = name = name[name.find(',')+2:]+", "+name[:name.find(',')]

Comment: the answer I get is the swapped positions, but still contains a comma in between

Comment: Well you're adding a comma into your string?  name[name.find(',')+2:] + **", "** + name[:name.find(',')]

Comment: OH, no wonder. Thank you kindly for your observation!

Comment: You're welcome.  I made an answer out of it.  You should take a look at @kojiro answer though, its a good answer.

Comment: We haven't really learned the slice notation [::]...
We've been taught [:] for slicing, but I don't really understand what [::] means. Does it slice the list twice?
say I have ['Riding hood']
[:4] will give ['Ridi']

Comment: Test it out and see what happens :)

Comment: The [::] keeps the items in the middle of the list? Say name = ['red', 'riding', 'hood']
name[::-1] will give ['hood', 'riding', 'red']
but name[:-1] will just give ['hood', 'red']

Answer (score 5):

1. You can split a string on commas into a list of strings using syntax like `astring.split(',')`
2. You can join a list of strings into a single string on whitespace like `' '.join(alist)`.
3. You can reverse a list using list slice notation: `alist[::-1]`
4. You can strip surrounding white space from a string using `astring.strip()`

Thus:

```
' '.join(aname.split(',')[::-1]).strip()
```

Answer (score 0):

You're adding the comma in yourself:

```
name = name[name.find(',')+2:] + ", " + name[:name.find(',')]
```

Make it:

```
name = name[name.find(',')+2:] + name[:name.find(',')]
```